# Solr - Combining automated crawl values and other manually entered data

Tags: solr, web-crawler, nutch

new to Solr and have implemented a crawl for specific URLs with Nutch/Solr.  If I add new fields to the Solr schema, can I still use it to crawl with Nutch and import into Solr without problems, or will the manually entered fields cause the crawl to not work properly?  Thank you for your time.

Comment: Welcome to SO :-) We usually expect that you try something before asking for help. If you try and hit problems, that would be the place here for help. But let's see if someone will answer it anyway.

Comment: Thanks - will try to do so in the future.  The reason I didn't try it is because I don't know how to yet and selfishly wanted to avoid the pain of learning how and then not having it work...but point well taken.

Answer (score 0):

Adding some fields to the Solr schema should not cause any trouble at all, keep in mind that this will be true unless you specify one of the new fields as `required` in which case an exception will be thrown. Otherwise you're fine. Of course since Nutch is unaware of these fields no value will be set during the Nutch crawl.